# df.replace not working when replacing a value in a row of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, row

I have tried the following code to rename 'Republic of Korea' to 'South Korea' in a dataframe with the columns  'Country', 'Energy supply', 'Energy Supply per Capita', '% Renewable'.

```
import pandas as pd

energy = pd.read_excel('Energy Indicators.xls',skiprows=17, skipfooter=38)

energy=energy.drop(['Unnamed: 0','Unnamed: 1'],axis=1)

energy.columns = ['Country', 'Energy Supply', 'Energy Supply per Capita', '% Renewable']

energy['Country'] = energy['Country'].str.replace(r" \(.*\)","")

energy['Country'] = energy['Country'].str.replace(r"(\d+)$","")

energy['Country'].replace({'Republic Of Korea': 'South Korea', 'United States of America': 'United States'}, inplace=True)
```

Then  I'm testing it to see the corresponding row in the dataframe.
When I search for 'Republic of Korea' I get this:

```
In:
energy[energy['Country']== 'Republic of Korea']

Out:
Country Energy Supply   Energy Supply per Capita    % Renewable

164 Republic of Korea   11007000000 221 2.279353
```

However, when I search for 'South Korea', nothing could be found (I just get the df labels).

```
In:
energy[energy['Country']== 'South Korea']


Out:
Country Energy Supply   Energy Supply per Capita    % Renewable
```

So I do not understand why the replace attribute does not work? I should be able to search for 'South Korea'?

Comment: There is probably a hidden space. Strip the spaces on the end of the strings and try again.

Comment: It works with 'United States'. It does not work with 'Republic of Korea'.

Comment: Just because it works with United states, doesn't mean theres not a hidden space after Repbulic of Korea.